# Why is unreachable code error not happening, where both try and finally have return

Tags: java, try-catch

```
  try {
            System.out.println("try1");
            return 1;
        } 
  finally {
            System.out.println("finally1");
            return 2;
        }
```

Here clearly output is

```
try1
finally1
2
```

return inside try is never executed. But compiler does not throw unreachable code error. Why?

Comment: "return inside try is never executed" - it *is* executed, but the return value is overridden by the return value from the `finally` block. There's no unreachable code here.

Comment: It's not unreachable per se. It's just superseded.

Comment: "return inside try is never executed." You can see that it is by making it execute a method that prints something before returning a value, e.g. `return methodThatPrintsBeforeReturningValue(1);`.